# resources exceeded in bigquery sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a simple cte query that removes duplicates.

```
with cte as (
   select     Agent_SK
    , Listing_Agent_License_Number
    , Listing_Agent_Name
    , Listing_Agent_Address
    , Listing_Agent_Phone
    , Listing_Agent_Email
    , Office_Name
    , Office_Address
    , Office_Phone
    , Office_Email
        , Update_Timestamp
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Listing_Agent_Name
                                        , Listing_Agent_Address
                                        , Listing_Agent_Phone
                                        , Listing_Agent_Email
                             ORDER BY Update_Timestamp DESC) AS rn
   from `mother-216719.VALUATION.MLS`
   where Agent_SK is not null
) select
    Agent_SK
    , Listing_Agent_License_Number
    , Listing_Agent_Name
    , Listing_Agent_Address
    , Listing_Agent_Phone
    , Listing_Agent_Email
    , Office_Name
    , Office_Address
    , Office_Phone
    , Office_Email
    , Update_Timestamp
from cte
where rn = 1;
```

This query is giving a exceeded resources.  I think it's about the `row_number()` function.  How can I go around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and should do the trick

```
#standardSQL
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT     
    Agent_SK
    , Listing_Agent_License_Number
    , Listing_Agent_Name
    , Listing_Agent_Address
    , Listing_Agent_Phone
    , Listing_Agent_Email
    , Office_Name
    , Office_Address
    , Office_Phone
    , Office_Email
    , Update_Timestamp
  FROM `mother-216719.VALUATION.MLS`
  WHERE Agent_SK IS NOT NULL
) 
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY Update_Timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] 
FROM cte t
GROUP BY     
  Listing_Agent_Name
  , Listing_Agent_Address
  , Listing_Agent_Phone
  , Listing_Agent_Email
```

Comment: I need to learn more about ARRAY_AGG.  That's the second time you saved me with that.  Thanks!